# Logo displayed when site is down should match the flair size

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow, flair, maintenance

I visited [my website](http://zachjohnson.net/) just now, and was greeted with the following StackOverflow logo display on my flair because StackOverflow was down for maintenance:

[image]
<sub>(source: [zachjohnson.net](http://zachjohnson.net/imagebin/stackoverflow/SO-down.png))</sub>

As you can see, the logo is truncated at the bottom and right-hand edges and thus looks rather ugly.

Could the displayed logo be re-sized to make it stay within the 210 x 60 flair size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declining this, [since this style of flair is now deprecated](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/23/flair-now-even-flairier/); The new image flair should not have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is a side-effect of the iframe used for the flair.  It's a happy coincidence that the logo is in the top left of the page here and even more so that you can see anything at all.  Additionally, it only works even this well for *planned* outages.

That said, they could (should) re-work the app_offline.htm file to take advantage of this, and for that matter even have a separate little asp.net "application" for displaying the flair, to prevent general updates from causing any interruption at all.